# Exptra parens generated after nested IFs libreoffice

Tags: if-statement, libreoffice, calc

I enter:

`=IF(D4=”4x4”, _4x4PT*e4, IF(D4=”4x6”,_4x6PT*e4, 0))`

when I press  I get:

Err:501

When I click on the cell I see:

`=IF(D4=”4x4”, _4x4PT*e4, IF(D4=”4x6”,_4x6PT*e4, 0)))`

Libreoffice has added an extra paren(s) at the end?

(`_4X4PT` and `_4x6PT` are cell names)
Substituting 7 and 11 for the two cell names makes no difference

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use smart quotes `”`. Calc expects normal quotes `"` instead. Now Calc will no longer add an extra parenthesis.

Depending on regional settings, you may now get `Err:508` and need to change the commas `,` to semicolons `;` instead. Semicolons are universally accepted by Calc as a delimiter.

Entering the following expression does not produce an error:

```
=IF(D4="4x4"; _4x4PT*e4; IF(D4="4x6";_4x6PT*e4; 0))
```